# What would be a good source to learn the Deuring-Heilbronn phenomenon?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I was trying to read from the book "Ten Lectures on the Interface Between Analytic Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis" by Montgomery. However, I found the text highly condense and difficult to read, probably because it's in the form of lecture notes. Can anyone please suggest a more manageable source for the Deuring-Heilbronn phenomenon and zero-repulsion as such?

Comment: If you are able to find it and you know French, you may try Enrico Bombieri, *Le Grand Crible dans la Théorie Analytique des Nombres*.

Comment: And there is always Terence Tao's blog: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/deuring-heilbronn-repulsion/

Comment: And there is this ("Notes on the DeuringHeilbronn
Phenomenon"):http://www.ams.org/notices/200608/fea-stopple.pdf